# How to get a list of the filenames of a specific folder in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to get all the filenames of a specific folder in a text file and I want only the names, not the relative path. I tried:

```
ls -1 a/b/c>filenames.txt
```

and its output is

```
file-2021-08-18.txt
file2-2021-08-18.js
file3-2021-08-18.json
file4-2021-08-19.json
```

which is what I want but only a specific day's file.

But when I do this:

```
ls -1 a/b/c/*2021-08-18*>filenames.txt
```

then the output is

```
a/b/c/file-2021-08-18.txt
a/b/c/file2-2021-08-18.js
a/b/c/file3-2021-08-18.json
```

I want only the filenames not the path of the files.
So, required output:

```
file-2021-08-18.txt
file2-2021-08-18.js
file3-2021-08-18.json
```

Is there any straightforward solution for this? OR I need to trim the output.

Thanks!!

Comment: ls (GNU coreutils) 8.22 & bash-4.2.46 on RHEL 7.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the argument to `ls` is a directory, it lists the filenames in the directory.

But when you use a wildcard, the shell expands the wildcard to all the filenames. So `ls` doesn't receive the directory as its argument, it receives all the filenames, and it lists them as given.

You can change to the directory and then list the matching files in the current directory:

```
(cd /a/b/c; ls *2021-08-18*) > filenames.txt
```

The parentheses make this run in a subshell, so the working directory of the original shell is unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `find` you may use the `-printf` option:

```
find a/b/c/ -type f -name "*2021-08-18*" -printf "%f\n" > filenames.txt
```

The directive `%f` picks out the file's name with any leading directories removed. Since `-printf` doesn't add a newline (`\n`) after the filename, we add one in order to match the required output.